# How to select a range in Excel using a variable for number of rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I know what I'm trying to do is simple, but I just cant seem to figure out how to do it. I am making a VBA macro in Excel, and what I'm trying to is select a certain number of rows (which will change each time I run the macro).

I get the number of rows like this:

```
Dim ThisRng As Range
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)

ThisRng.Rows.Count 'This is my number of rows
```

So I have my number of rows in that variable, now what I want to do is select the range of cells starting at cell I3, all the way down for my number of rows. For example, say my number of rows is 20, I want to select the range of cells from I3 to I23 to apply the formula.

Obviously I can't do Range("I3:I(ThisRng.Rows.Count)").Select, but that's essentially what I want to do. I just don't know the syntax. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `Range("I3").Resize(ThisRng.Rows.Count + 1)`.

Comment: Note that `"` characters in VBA delimit `String` literals; you can use the `&` concatenation operator to concatenate a string literal with a local variable's value, for example. So `someSheet.Range("I3:I" & ThisRng.Rows.Count)`.

Comment: Though that would return `I3:I20`, not `I3:I23`.